# How to pass data from one listview to another listview on another activity

Tags: android, json, listview

working with php mysql multiple table and json need to pass data from one listview to another listview on another activity

i have been able to list the first listview activity  i need to pass a foreign key which will enable me to get the details of the record in the second listview in the second activity

DetailsActivity.java

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        PostResponseAsyncTask taskRead = new PostResponseAsyncTask(DetailActivity.this, this);
        taskRead.execute("http://10.0.3.2/mcause/caseList.php");


        String Courtroom ="";
        String Casedate = "";
        String Suiteno = "";
        String Litigants = "";
        String Judge = "";

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Intent in = getIntent();
        if(null != in){
           Courtroom = in.getStringExtra(Courtroom);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void processFinish(String s) {
        casesList = new JsonConverter<Cases>().toArrayList(s, Cases.class);
        BindDictionary<Cases> dict = new BindDictionary<Cases>();
        dict.addStringField(R.id.Casedate, new StringExtractor<Cases>() {
            @Override
            public String getStringValue(Cases item, int position) {
                return item.CaseDate;
            }
        });

        dict.addStringField(R.id.Suiteno, new StringExtractor<Cases>() {
            @Override
            public String getStringValue(Cases item, int position) {
                return item.Suiteno;
            }
        });

        dict.addStringField(R.id.Litigants, new StringExtractor<Cases>() {
            @Override
            public String getStringValue(Cases item, int position) {
                return item.Litigants;
            }
        });

        dict.addStringField(R.id.Judge, new StringExtractor<Cases>() {
            @Override
            public String getStringValue(Cases item, int position) {
                return item.Judge;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post PostResponseAsyncTask code .

Comment: have you tried passing it through an intent? Looks like you are doing that in your `onCreate` method, con you confirm?

Comment: please can you be more specific